# SwiftUI onReceive don't work with UIPasteboard publisher

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, uipasteboard

I would like to subscribe to UIPasteboard changes in SwiftUI with onReceive.
`pHasStringsPublisher` will not be updated as soon as something in the clipboard changes and I don't understand why.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
    
    @State var pString: String = "pString"
    @State var pHasStrings: Bool = false
    @State var pHasStringsPublisher: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            Text("b: '\(self.pString)'")
                .font(.headline)
            Text("b: '\(self.pHasStrings.description)'")
                .font(.headline)
            Text("p: '\(self.pHasStringsPublisher.description)'")
                .font(.headline)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                self.pString = self.pasteboard.string ?? "nil"
                self.pHasStrings = self.pasteboard.hasStrings
            }, label: {
                Text("read pb")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            })
            Button(action: {
                self.pasteboard.items = []
            }, label: {
                Text("clear pb")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            })
            Button(action: {
                self.pasteboard.string = Date().description
            }, label: {
                Text("set pb")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            })
            
        }
        .onReceive(self.pasteboard
                    .publisher(for: \.hasStrings)
                    .print()
                    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                   , perform:
                    { hasStrings in
                        print("pasteboard publisher")
                        self.pHasStringsPublisher = hasStrings
                    })
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure `hasStrings` is a KVO-compliant property? The `publisher(for: KeyPath` method only works with KVO-compliant properties, since it uses KVO under the hood. The documentation of that property does not mention it being KVO-compliant, so I'd suspect it actually isn't. You need to find another way to observe pasteboard changes.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was not aware of KVO-compliant properties, but I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, none of `UIPasteboard`'s properties are documented to support Key-Value Observing (KVO), so `publisher(for: \.hasStrings)` may not ever publish anything.

Instead, you can listen for `UIPasteboard.changedNotification` from the default `NotificationCenter`. But if you are expecting the user to copy in a string from another application, that is still not sufficient, because a pasteboard doesn't post `changedNotification` if its content was changed while your app was in the background. So you **also** need to listen for `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification`.

Let's wrap it all up in an extension on `UIPasteboard`:

```
extension UIPasteboard {
    var hasStringsPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        return Just(hasStrings)
            .merge(
                with: NotificationCenter.default
                    .publisher(for: UIPasteboard.changedNotification, object: self)
                    .map { _ in self.hasStrings })
            .merge(
                with: NotificationCenter.default
                    .publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
                    .map { _ in self.hasStrings })
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            blah blah blah
        }
        .onReceive(UIPasteboard.general.hasStringsPublisher) { hasStrings = $0 }
    }
```